# User preference client-server dialogue

Tags: web, web-applications, client-server, standards

Is there any established standard, or guideline, which would specify client-server dialogue regarding preference of any parameters?

### Example

Let's consider all the websites with embedded code editor.
Regardless of website, or the editor, I'd like to be able to specify, the preference of coloring schema. Let's say monokai.

Is there any standardized way of handling something like that?

What I imagine is that, as a user I'd have a chrome extension in which I would specify my preferences and when I request the website, there is either the value indicating usage of code editor in the html, either server asks user if it has any preference, which I don't really see how it should work.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question. The idea is that you'd like the user to be able to configure preferences which are shared between multiple sites, so that when the user goes to your site you can first check their preference and default to that value instead of requiring them to explicitly configurate that preference for your website. Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming my understanding is correct, there isn't a standard for accomplishing this, outside of some narrow areas such as language preferences or dark mode which are built into browsers. Theoretically, any preference could be relayed via HTTP request headers, but that's not terribly useful unless enough sites agree upon a standard and client browsers (or, as you suggest, extensions) facilitate collecting and relaying that data. Alternatively, this might be accomplished using a cookie on a third-party domain whose value can be retrieved via JavaScript.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Yes. Similarly how it works for UNIX systems. General standard is to specify preferences as environment variables. I was thinking about using HTML meta tags, on the server side, for indicating usage of the standardization